# Adding custom prefixes that are ignored when sorting by subject in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I would like to add the word "EXTERNAL:" to the list of subject prefixes like "RE:" and "FW:" that are ignored when sorting by subject in Outlook 2007.

For example, this message is sorted as if the subject was simply "Some Subject".

```
From: me@a.com
To: them@b.com
Subject: RE: Some Subject
```

This reply is sorted as if the subject was "EXTERNAL: RE: Some Subject". (B.com's server is set up so that the word "EXTERNAL:" is added to the subject for emails that originate outside of b.com.)

```
From: them@b.com
To: me@a.com
Subject: RE: EXTERNAL: RE: Some Subject
```

As an Outlook end user, how would I make the second email sort as if its subject was "Some Subject"?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is to change internal message property SubjectPrefix. You can achieve the desired result by using *free* [Set Header Value](http://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookHeadersSet/) utility. Just specify **SubjectPrefix** as a  *Header name* and **EXTERNAL:** as a *Value to set*.

You can do many things by manipulating Outlook message properties.